# Get WKT from polygon centroid

Tags: oracle-spatial, sdo-geometry

I have an Oracle Spatial table (in 12c) with a polygon geometry type. I added a text column to the table that I would like to populate with the well-known text of the polygon's centroid. In concept this is really simple but I'm having trouble using the `SDO_CENTROID` function properly. This is my SQL statement so far:

```
update parcel
set centroid_wkt = sdo_util.to_wktgeometry(sdo_geom.sdo_centroid(shape,  usgm.diminfo))
from user_sdo_geom_metadata usgm;
```

When I execute this it tells me `SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`. Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong here? My guess is that the `UPDATE... SET... FROM...` syntax doesn't work in Oracle, but I'm not sure how else to select the `diminfo` array.

Comment: For what do you need anything from sdo_geom_metadata?

Comment: It's a required argument, isn't it? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objgeom.htm#i860848

Comment: You are right, I did not remember how tricky it is with Oracle. The update query will be even more tricky because you will  need to make a sub-query and use alias for it. I may come back to this but only after a week or so, sorry.

Comment: It is NOT a required argument. It is just there to get the tolerance for the operation. But you can just pass that directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to pass the metadata. Just pass your tolerance setting explicitly, like this:

```
update parcel
set centroid_wkt = sdo_util.to_wktgeometry(sdo_geom.sdo_centroid(shape,0.05));
```

Assuming your data is in geodetic coordinates, or is in a projection that uses meters as base unit, then 0.05 means 5cm.